# How to get twitter new followers by using API in php?

Tags: php, twitter

i need to get twitter new followers using twitter API. I am able to get total followers but not able to get NEW followers.

```
$obj = new TwitterOAuth($keys['AppKey'], $keys['SecretKey'],$sKey2,$sKey3);
$detail = $obj->get('account/verify_credentials');
$return=$return+$detail->followers_count;
```

**How to get new followers not total followers?**

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids: _“At this time, results are ordered with the most recent following first — however, this ordering is subject to unannounced change and eventual consistency issues.”_ So you should not rely on this in the first place; if you want to do it nevertheless, you will have to save the id of the “latest” follower on your end, and then when you request followers the next time see which “new” ones are returned before that id.

Answer (score 1):

For authorized users you can use Twitter Stream API for track new followers:
https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types#Events_event

I use it with C# library https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi
and code is very simple:

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
var stream = Stream.CreateUserStream();
stream.FollowedByUser += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have been followed by " + args.User);
};
stream.StartStream();
```

I think there is same library for php too. Or you can try use Twitter Stream API from php directly